# Create listener for external resource change in eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse rcp application I need to add some functionality that makes it possible to listen to eg. the content of an external folder and process the content if it has changed.

Does the eclipse sdk offer any functionality for this or should I simply implement my own thread that check the folder within a specified internal?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not have any specific functionality for this.

You best option probably is to create a new Eclipse Job that will scan the folder periodically using the basic `File.list()`...